# How can I use importvalue in a Cloudforamtion object?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I would like to reference an Importvalue in the following Object, but I can't get it to work.
I want to put the value of the export name from another stack.

```
Input: !Sub "{\"InstanceId\":[\"{ Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${ProjectName}-ec2-instance-id }\"],\"AutomationAssumeRole\":[\"${EC2AmazonSSMAutomationRole.Arn}\"]}"
```

Comment: What is the full template? What errors do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but the values of the constants in the rules created are not converting properly.

Comment: {
  "InstanceId": ["{ Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ec2-instance-id }"],
  "AutomationAssumeRole": ["arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/tao-training-roule-EC2AmazonSSMAutomationRole-19Q1I7TTPO80E"]
}

Comment: The value of InstanceId is assumed to be the export name of another stack.